# Why I can't receive broacast when downloadmanager finish download?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Why I can't receive broacast when downloadmanager finish download?
My BrocastReceiver is registered in manifest.xml. I have added ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.
I also add permissions.

Comment: have you registered your receiver form main activity?

Comment: no.I just register it in manifest.xml.

Comment: Do it must be registered in activity?

Comment: yes I faced same problem too and guys here told me so and it works ill link you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066500/android-sms-receiver-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the below link [Android DownloadManager Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-downloadmanager-example.html)

Comment: yes. it is a good example. But in the example, you must stay activity, if you desdroy your activity, you will ungister receiver. What I want is when I leave my activity, I still can receiver broacast.

Answer (score 0):

you can registerReceiver in application's onCreate, if you want receive broadcast even if leave some activity, Note that you must use context.registerReceiver and do not use LocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver.
good luck!